# Store different data to each tab

Tags: php, javascript, session

I need store different *post* data to each tab in a browser. If I open a new instance of the same page, the data aren't shared between both.

**My problem**:

I'm building a CMS to control my website content. But I will open some instances of the same page (many tabs). So I have a search form to find *news* that I been created on my CMS. If I open a news item I have a *cancel* button that back to previous page (the news list).

The problem is that the news list have a pagination and a filter form. So I can, for instance, search by a term like "*john doe*" and advance to page 5, and open a news item. If I cancel, currently I back to news list without filter and on first page.

**My solutions**:

Well, I don't want to use the `history.back()` because I can submit a news form and click on back/cancel button. So, I'll back to the current form, what is wrong.

My second idea is to store a `$_SESSION` with the `$_POST` sent to the news list and the back button send me to `/news/list/recovery-session`, that will recovery the `$_POST` data from session. But it have a problem: if I open two tabs and make two searchs, I'll have only the last session saved.

**Your solutions**:

Well, I can work with PHP and JS to make it work. You can suggest a idea of what I can do. I think about work with COOKIES, but I belive that it is shared by domain, and not by tab, what is a problem.

Someone?

Answer (score 1):

Generate a unique id and attach it to the form or some hidden element that will be submitted. Save that unique id in a cookie or session variable. Compare the two at time of submission.

If second tab has generated a new id, the first tab will not evaluate to true.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is the need to persist the state of *what page to return to* and also the *search term* when returning back to the news list page. There are many ways to accomplish this, but one simple method is by encoding this data into your query string.

As an example, assuming your search term is "john doe" and you are on page 5, pass that data along to your news page.

```
 news.php?returnSearchTerm=john+doe&returnPage=5& ....
```

When the news page is created, you can format your cancel link to send you back to the list page with the correct parameters.

```
 news_list.php?search=john+doe&page=5
```